# Best way to log requests from a servlet and to a database?

Tags: java, database, logging

I am providing a RESTful service that is being served by a servlet (running inside Tomcat 7.0.X and Ubuntu Linux). I'm already getting about 20 thousand queries per hour and it will grow much higher. The servlet receives the requests, prepares the response, inserts a records in a MySQL database table and delivers the response. The log in the database is absolutely mandatory. Untily recently, all this happened in a syncronous way. I mean, before the Tomcat thread delivered the response, it had to create the records in the database table. The problem is that this log used to take more than 90% of the total time, and even worse: when the database got slower then the service took about 10-15 seconds instead of just 20 miliseconds.

I recetly made an improvement: Each Tomcat thread creates an extra thread doing a "(new Thread(new certain Object)).start();" that takes care of the SQL insertion in an asyncronous way, so the response gets to the clients faster. But these threads take too much RAM when MySQL runs slower and threads multiply, and with a few thousands of them the JVM Tomcat runs of the memory.

What I need is to be able to accept as much HTTP requests as possible, to log every one of them as fast as possible (not syncronously), and to make everything fast and with a very low usage of RAM when MySQL gets slow and inserts need to queue. I think I need some kind of queue to buffer the entries when the speed of http request is higher than the speed of insertions in the database log.

I'm thinking about these ideas:

1- Creating some kind of FIFO queue myself, maybe using some of those Apache commons collections, and the some kind of thread that polls the collection and creates the database records. But what collection should I use? And how should I program the thread that polls it, so it won't monopolize the CPU? I think that a "Do while (true)...." would eat the CPU cycles. And that about making it thread safe? How to do it? I think doing it myself is too much effort and most likely I will reinvent the wheel.

2- log4J? I have never used it directly, but it seems that this framework is algo designed to creat "appenders" that talk to the database. Would that be the way to do it?

3- Using some kind of any other framework that specializes in this?

What would you suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to consider buffering your logs into an in-memory cache like memcached, then doing bulk writes to the DB at periodic intervals.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind right away is a queue like you said. You can use things like ActiveMQ http://activemq.apache.org/ or RabbitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com/.

The idea is to just fire and forget. There should be almost no overhead to send the messages.

Then you can connect some "offline" to pick up messages off the queues and write them to the database at the speed you need.

I feel like I plug this all day on Stack Overflow, but we use Mule (http://www.mulesoft.org/) at work to do this. One of the great things about Mule is that you can explicitly set the number of threads that read from the queue and the number of threads that write to the database. It allows you fine grain control over throttling messages.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at using a ThreadPoolExecutor. You can provide the thread pool size, and it will handle all the concurrency and queuing for you. Only possible issue is that if your JVM crashes for any reason, you'll lose any queued items in your pool.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

I would also definitely look into optimizing the MySQL database as much as possible. 20k entries per hour can get hairy pretty quickly. The better optimized your hardware, os, and indexes the quicker your inserts and smaller your queue will be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions!

So far I have found a partial solution to my need, and I already implemented it succesfully:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

Now I'm thinking about using also a queue provider if that gets full, as a failover solution. So far I have thought about Amazon's queue service, but it costs money. I will also check the queue solutions that Ryan suggested.